# why am i getting an error/ why is the formatting incorrect?

Tags: python, formatting

I keep getting either an error working with f literals in Python. I've run into the same problem on two occasions where the result is an integer and a boolean value.

```
def verify(result):
    print("Target found:",result)


numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
result = recursive_binary_search(numbers, 6)
verify(result)
```

Prints:

```
('Target found:', True)
```

tried with f literals

```
def verify(result):
    print(f"Target found:{result}")
```

Prints:

```
              print(f"Target found:{result}")
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That the output of `print("Target found:",result)` is `('Target found:', True)` and not `Target found: True` reveals that you are using Python 2. You are printing a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 2. f-strings are a Python 3 feature, the equivalent in Python 2 is

```
print "Target found: {}".format(result)
```

Comment: Not just Python 3; f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6.

Comment: Python 2 also had a `print` function, though it had to be enabled with a `__future__` import. Even if they hadn't, `print("...")` would simply be parsed as a `print` statement with an unnecessarily parenthesized `str` value.